# ¿Cómo usar Chartjs al instalarlo como npm?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, chart.js

Instalé chartjs como npm de forma local y quiero llamarlo desde un script que está en mi carpeta estática public en el lado del frontend

```
import {Chart} from "chart.js/auto";

const printCharts = () =>{
    renderModeisCharts();
};

const renderModeisCharts = () =>{
    const ctx = getElementById(`modelsChart`);
    const  data = {
        label:[uno,dos,tres],
        datasets:[{ data:[10,20  ,30]}]
        
    }
    new Chart(ctx,{type:'bar', data });
}

printCharts();
```

pero al ser estática el `require()` no me sirve y el import me da un error

> ¨uncaught syntaxerror: cannot use import statement outside a module¨.

Quisiera saber cómo solucionar esto o cuál es el método para poder inyectar desde el backend una gráfica dinámica hecha con esta librería en mi código HTML.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import

Comment: Y si usas un CDN como en el [ejemplo](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/)? https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html

Comment: Que framework estas usando en el FrontEnd? En Vue por ejemplo, una vez instalas chartjs con npm, importas la libreria, y tambien importas la plantilla del grafico del paquete instalado

Comment: Es verdad que se puede usar CDN pero si buscamos en internet no encontraremos casi absolutamente sobre este tema y quisiera superarme. No estoy usando ningun framework frontend en particular. En cuanto a link del primer comentario el usa una herramienta browsefiry. Si los diseñadores de esta librería permitieron que se pudiera instalar como npm de forma local debe existir algún modo de usarla en nodejs puramente sin depender de terceros.